# Please can anyone explain this code i m working on email sending php code and i found this code on GitHub?

Tags: php

```
private function getSMTPSettingList()
{
    $configs = OW::getConfig()->getValues('base');

    return array(
        'connectionPrefix' => $configs['mail_smtp_connection_prefix'],
        'host' => $configs['mail_smtp_host'],
        'port' => $configs['mail_smtp_port'],
        'user' => $configs['mail_smtp_user'],
        'password' => $configs['mail_smtp_password']
    );
}
```

This is a code i found on GitHub of oxwal mail service.php

### I m new in php so i was taking help from this code...but i could not understand anything of it......

### this is whole code now how do i use this functions to send email from my website...

class BOL_MailService
   {

```
const MAIL_COUNT_PER_CRON_JOB = 50;

const TRANSFER_SMTP = 'smtp';
const TRANSFER_MAIL = 'mail';
const TRANSFER_SENDMAIL = 'sendmail';
private $mailDao;
private $defaultMailSettingList = array();

private function __construct()
{
    $this->mailDao = BOL_MailDao::getInstance();

    $siteName = OW::getConfig()->getValue('base', 'site_name');
    $siteEmail = OW::getConfig()->getValue('base', 'site_email');
    $senderSuffix = defined('OW_SENDER_MAIL_SUFFIX') ? OW_SENDER_MAIL_SUFFIX : null;

    $this->defaultMailSettingList = array(
        'sender' => array($siteEmail, $siteName),
        'senderSuffix' => intval($senderSuffix)
    );
}
/**
 * Class instance
 *
 * @var BOL_MailService
 */
private static $classInstance;

/**
 *
 * @var PHPMailer
 */
private $phpMailer;

/**
 * Returns class instance
 *
 * @return BOL_MailService
 */
public static function getInstance()
{
    if ( !isset(self::$classInstance) )
    {
        self::$classInstance = new self();
    }

    return self::$classInstance;
}

/**
 *
 * @return PHPMailer
 */
private function getMailer()
{
    if ( !isset($this->phpMailer) )
    {
        $this->phpMailer = $this->initializeMailer($this->getTransfer());
    }

    return $this->phpMailer;
}

/**
 *
 * @return PHPMailer
 */
private function initializeMailer( $transfer )
{
    $mailer = new PHPMailer(true);

    switch ( $transfer )
    {
        case self::TRANSFER_SMTP :
            $this->smtpSetup($mailer);
            break;
        case self::TRANSFER_SENDMAIL :
            $mailer->IsSendmail();
            break;
        case self::TRANSFER_MAIL :
            $mailer->IsMail();
            break;
    }

    $mailer->CharSet = "utf-8";

    return $mailer;
}

public function getTransfer()
{
    if ( OW::getConfig()->getValue('base', 'mail_smtp_enabled') )
    {
        return self::TRANSFER_SMTP;
    }

    return self::TRANSFER_MAIL;
}

private function getSMTPSettingList()
{
    $configs = OW::getConfig()->getValues('base');

    return array(
        'connectionPrefix' => $configs['mail_smtp_connection_prefix'],
        'host' => $configs['mail_smtp_host'],
        'port' => $configs['mail_smtp_port'],
        'user' => $configs['mail_smtp_user'],
        'password' => $configs['mail_smtp_password']
    );
}

/**
 *
 * @param PHPMailer $mailer
 */
private function smtpSetup( $mailer )
{
    $settingList = $this->getSMTPSettingList();

    $mailer->SMTPSecure = $settingList['connectionPrefix'];
    $mailer->IsSMTP();
    $mailer->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mailer->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
    $mailer->Host = $settingList['host'];

    if ( !empty($settingList['port']) )
    {
        $mailer->Port = (int) $settingList['port'];
    }

    $mailer->Username = $settingList['user'];
    $mailer->Password = $settingList['password'];
}

public function smtpTestConnection()
{
    if ( $this->getTransfer() !== self::TRANSFER_SMTP )
    {
        throw new LogicException('Mail transfer is not SMTP');
    }

    $mailer = $this->getMailer();

    try
    {
        return $mailer->SmtpConnect();
    }
    catch ( phpmailerException $e )
    {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException($e->getMessage());
    }
}

/**
 *
 * @return BASE_CLASS_Mail
 */
public function createMail()
{
    $mail = new BASE_CLASS_Mail($this->defaultMailSettingList);

    return $mail;
}

private function createMailFromDto( BOL_Mail $mailDto )
{
    $mail = new BASE_CLASS_Mail();
    $mail->addRecipientEmail($mailDto->recipientEmail);
    $mail->setSender($mailDto->senderEmail, $mailDto->senderName);
    $mail->setSubject($mailDto->subject);
    $mail->setTextContent($mailDto->textContent);
    $mail->setHtmlContent($mailDto->htmlContent);
    $mail->setSentTime($mailDto->sentTime);
    $mail->setPriority($mailDto->priority);
    $mail->setSenderSuffix($mailDto->senderSuffix);

    return $mail;
}

private function prepareFromEmail( $email, $suffix )
{
    if ( empty($email) )
    {
        return null;
    }

    $suffix = intval($suffix);

    if ( empty($suffix) )
    {
        return $email;
    }

    list($user, $provider) = explode('@', $email);

    return $user . '+' . $suffix . '@' . $provider;
}

public function send( BASE_CLASS_Mail $mail )
{
    $mailer = $this->getMailer();
    $mailState = $mail->saveToArray();

    $event = new OW_Event('base.mail_service.send.check_mail_state', array(), $mailState);
    OW::getEventManager()->trigger($event);
    $mailState = $event->getData();

    if ( empty($mailState['recipientEmailList']) )
    {
        return false;
    }

    $fromEmail = $this->prepareFromEmail($mailState['sender'][0], $mailState['senderSuffix']);

    $mailer->SetFrom($fromEmail, $mailState['sender'][1]);
    $mailer->Sender = $mailState['sender'][0];

    if ( !empty($mailState['replyTo']) )
    {
        $mailer->AddReplyTo($mailState['replyTo'][0], $mailState['replyTo'][1]);
    }
    foreach ( $mailState['recipientEmailList'] as $item )
    {
        $mailer->AddAddress($item);
    }

    $isHtml = !empty($mailState['htmlContent']);

    $mailer->Subject = $mailState['subject'];
    $mailer->IsHTML($isHtml);
    $mailer->Body = $isHtml ? $mailState['htmlContent'] : $mailState['textContent'];
    $mailer->AltBody = $isHtml ? $mailState['textContent'] : '';

    $result = $mailer->Send();
    $mailer->ClearReplyTos();
    $mailer->ClearAllRecipients();

    return $result;
}

private function mailToDtoList( BASE_CLASS_Mail $mail )
{
    $mailState = $mail->saveToArray();
    $resultList = array();

    foreach ( $mailState['recipientEmailList'] as $email )
    {
        $mailDto = new BOL_Mail();

        $mailDto->senderEmail = $mailState['sender'][0];
        $mailDto->senderName = $mailState['sender'][1];
        $mailDto->subject = $mailState['subject'];
        $mailDto->textContent = $mailState['textContent'];
        $mailDto->htmlContent = $mailState['htmlContent'];
        $mailDto->sentTime = empty($mailState['sentTime']) ? time() : $mailState['sentTime'];
        $mailDto->priority = $mailState['priority'];
        $mailDto->recipientEmail = $email;
        $mailDto->senderSuffix = intval($mailState['senderSuffix']);

        $resultList[] = $mailDto;
    }

    return $resultList;
}

public function addToQueue( BASE_CLASS_Mail $mail )
{
    $dtoList = $this->mailToDtoList($mail);

    foreach ( $dtoList as $dtoMail )
    {
        $this->mailDao->save($dtoMail);
    }
}

public function addListToQueue( array $mailList )
{
    $fullDtoList = array();

    foreach ( $mailList as $mail )
    {
        $dtoList = $this->mailToDtoList($mail);

        foreach ( $dtoList as $mailDto )
        {
            $fullDtoList[] = $mailDto;
        }
    }

    if ( !empty($fullDtoList) )
    {
        $this->mailDao->saveList($fullDtoList);
    }
}

public function processQueue( $count = self::MAIL_COUNT_PER_CRON_JOB )
{
    $list = $this->mailDao->findList($count);

    $processedIdList = array();

    foreach ( $list as $item )
    {
        try
        {
            $mail = $this->createMailFromDto($item);
            $this->send($mail);
        }
        catch ( Exception $e )
        {
            //Skip invalid email adresses
        }

        $this->mailDao->updateSentStatus($item->id);
    }

    $this->mailDao->deleteSentMails();
}

public function getEmailDomain()
{
    switch ( $this->getTransfer() )
    {
        case self::TRANSFER_SMTP:
            $settings = $this->getSMTPSettingList();
            return $settings['host'];

        default:
            $urlInfo = parse_url(OW_URL_HOME);
            return $urlInfo['host'];
    }
}

public function deleteQueuedMailsByRecipientId( $userId )
{
    $user = BOL_UserService::getInstance()->findUserById($userId);

    if ( $user === null )
    {
        return;
    }

    $this->mailDao->deleteByRecipientEmail($user->email);
}

public function __destruct()
{
    $this->getMailer()->SmtpClose();
}
```

}

Comment: this function is only returning STMP setting of your mail server like it's `host,port,username,password etc...` so that you can use it further in your code to do SMTP connection for sending mail.The function name and it's return value is self explanatory that what this function is doing.I don't know what you unable to understand here?

Comment: I understood the code but i could not understand how it used to send the email using php mailer...i will. Post the whole code where. I m not able to understand

Answer (score 0):

This is simple PHP mail function to send mail

```
 $to      = $email_id;
 $subject = "Test Subject";
 $message = "Your mail Body Content. you also use here HTML Tags for better UI. ";
 $headers = 'From: xyz@domainname.com' . "\r\n" .
  'Reply-To: xyz@domainname.com' . "\r\n" .
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
 $headers.= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
 $headers.= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

 $test=mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Or download PHPMailer library and refer below example

```
ini_set('SMTP', "smtp.gmail.com"); // Your domain SMTP
ini_set('smtp_port', "465"); // here we write your domain SMTP port
ini_set('sendmail_from', "xxxx@domain.com"); // your email make sure email id is available on above mention SMTP 
ini_Set('password',"xxxxxx"); // email account password


require 'C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\PHPMailer_5.2.4\class.phpmailer.php'; //load phpmailer library here

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->IsSMTP();         // send via SMTP
//IsSMTP();             // send via SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Host="smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Mailer="smtp"; // domain SMTP
$mail->port=465; // Domain mail port
$mail->Username = "abc@gmail.com";   // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "xxxxx";      // SMTP password

$webmaster_email = "abc@gmail.com";     //Reply to this email ID
$email="abc@test.com";                 // Recipients email ID
$name="Test mail";             // Recipient's name
$mail->From = $webmaster_email;
$mail->FromName = "Test Name";
$mail->AddAddress($email,$name);
$mail->AddReplyTo($webmaster_email,"Webmaster");
$mail->WordWrap = 50; // set word wrap
$mail->AddAttachment("/var/tmp/file.tar.gz");        // attachment
$mail->AddAttachment("/tmp/image.jpg", "new.jpg");   // attachment
$mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML
$mail->Subject = "Thanks For Connecting";
$mail->Body = "This is your mail body"; //HTML Body
$mail->AltBody = "This is the body when user views in plain text format";     //Text Body
if(!$mail->Send())
{
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
    echo "Message has been sent";
}
```